# Enterprise_Index_Exception with message "Can't lock indexer process"

Tags: magento-enterprise, cron, schedule

I am seeing above message in list view of scheduler. The status is "Success" though. Last updated time of the lock file in var/locks is keep changing to latest time, meaning the it's been used. I am just wondering if this is a the planned behaviour? Or something wrong?
[image]

```
exception 'Enterprise_Index_Exception' with message 'Can't lock indexer process.' in /var/www/app/code/core/Enterprise/Index/Model/Observer.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Enterprise_Index_Model_Observer->refreshIndex(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#1 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(263): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), true)
#3 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(89): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processAlwaysTask('enterprise_refr...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#4 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatchAlways(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatchAlways', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('always', Array)
#7 /var/www/cron.php(77): Mage::dispatchEvent('always')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if AOE_Secheduler supports the always running cron in latest EE. May be something to poke around the github account for insight. https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues

Comment: can you please include the error message as text?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Can you please ask questions if you think its unclear? What other information do you want? The first comment suggest that he understood it right? May be you should lean magento first before putting stuff on hold just because you did not understand it?

Comment: Just in case anyone having the same issue, the message is last knows message, hence if an error is occurred in the indexing, this is going to continue to be shown unless there is a particular success message. Hope will save time for anyone else. I cannot add it as an answer, as someone seems to think they don't have enough information in the question :D

Comment: @brentwpeterson 7ochem kab8609 liyakat amit-bera what is unclear about this question?